# Method Not Allowed on $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I was following [this tutroial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#deleting-articles) and everything is working fine, except the Deleting Articles. When I'm calling delete method:

```
public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

        $job = $this->Jobs->get($id);
        if ($this->Jobs->delete($job)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Job: {0} has been deleted.', h($job->name)));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
    }
```

I have this error:

> **Method Not Allowed**: $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

But if i remove this line from my method, it works:

```
$this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
```

So what am I doing wrong, and what I'm missing, why in the tutorial it works with this, but in my case it doesn't. Should I additionally allow something?

> Here is php code of the action:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Delete',    array('controller' => 'Jobs','action' => 'delete', $job->id),
                                    array('confirm' => 'Are You Sure?','class' => 'button red'));
```

> Here is html code of the action:

```
<a href="/jobsfind/jobs/delete/32" class="button red" onclick="if (confirm(&quot;Are You Sure?&quot;)) { return true; } return false;">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Well, the most obvious reason would be that you are neither sending a `POST`, nor a `DELETE` request. So you should check that and show the results in case this turns out to be true. Also please show your form code and the generated HTML.

Comment: Yeah, using normal links and then requiring a post is a pretty nonsense thing to do. That's what postLink() and CO are for.

Comment: @mark well, I was following the steps in official CakePHP3.0 cookbook.

Comment: actuall @mark you was right, i replaced $this->Html->link with $this->Form->postLink and it's working now.

Comment: I hope you now understand **why** it wasnt working and why I wrote what I wrote :)

Comment: Not really, but I'll look into it, some hints would be nice :) I guess it's because Form object automatically adds POST method, or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, that Your request is `GET` and not `DELETE`. So, You should use `AJAX` and define type of Your request:

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'DELETE',
  data : 'post_id=' + post_id,
  success : function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
})
```

This piece of code might help. If no - just use `GET` request to remove, because `POST` request commonly using for adding data.

Or You should provide hash with tokens that will be checking in [Middleware](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html).